# Workflow Context Initiator mistakenly displaying the publisher and not the initiator of the workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I am working in a SharePoint online environment. I have created and published various SharePoint Designer workflows from my personal account. A particular user is initiating a workflow which retrieves the Workflow Context: Initiator (Email address) and passes it to an HTTP Web Service call to authenticate it against a permission group in a piece of CSOM C# code exposed in an HTTP Web service method. For some reason, the Initiator is always logging my personal account and not the account of the user starting the workflow.

Any ideas?